# Raabe's Test for convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

So I'm reading along in the book and come across Raabe's test for convergence.

$\frac {\vert x_n+1|}{|x_n|}\le1-a/n $

for k>N, $\sum x_n$ converges

$\frac {\vert x_n+1|}{|x_n|}\ge1-a/n $

for k>N $\sum x_n$ does not converge

---

so $\sum n^p$ for p>1,

$$\lim n(1-\frac {n^p}{(n+1)^p})=\lim n\frac {(n+1)^p-n^p}{(n+1)^p}$$

applying L'Hospital's rule the book has a fraction that I recognize neither as the product nor the derivative. Could somebody please help as to how they got this?

$$ =\lim \frac {(1+1/n)^p-1}{1/n}\circ \lim \frac {1}{(1+1/n)^p} $$

which conveniently equals p, thus proving divergence.

Answer (score 1):

An idea, which I think is seriously simpler: with continuous variable $\;n\;$ (to apply l'Hospital),

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{n^p}{(n+1)^p}}{\frac1n}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-\frac{pn^{p-1}(n+1)-pn^p}{(n+1)^{p+1}}}{-\frac1{n^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,p\,\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{p+1}=p$$

Comment: I wish I knew where they got (1+1/n), but your way makes sense. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: @Tim It is just the very same expression written differently!:$$\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^p-1}{\frac1n}\cdot\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^p}=\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^p-1}{\frac1n\left(1+\frac1n\right)^p}=\frac{(n+1)^p-n^p}{\require{cancel}\cancel{n^p}\,\frac1n\,\frac{(n+1)^p}{\cancel{n^p}}}=n\left(1-\frac{n^p}{(n+1)^p}\right)$$

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.